# Filter search in table except for 1 column in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

can you please help me how to filter search field except for 1 column 'transaction_id' column in table.

//////HTML

```
 <mat-form-field appearance="standard" style="width: 18rem">
      <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
      <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter()" [(ngModel)]="search_word" placeholder="Search here" autocomplete="off"
        #input />
    </mat-form-field> 

 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>


</table>
```

////component.ts

```
 async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    await this.allTransactionViewdata();
   
  }

  allTransactionViewdata() {

    
    return new Promise(resolve =>{
      this.spinner.show()
      this.tservice.getAllTransactionData().subscribe(
        (res: any) => {


            this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.tableArr);
            this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
            this.dataSource.sort = this.sorts;
            this.tservice.tableArry = _.cloneDeep(this.tableArr);

          }
          this.applyFilter();

          this.spinner.hide()
          resolve(true)
      
        },
        (error) => {
          this.spinner.hide()
          console.log(error.message);
        }
      );
    })

  applyFilter() {
    const filterValue = this.search_word;
    
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();

    
    if (this.dataSource.paginator) {
      this.dataSource.paginator.firstPage();
    }
  }
```

I need to return the table filter except for 1 column. Help must appreciated. Thank you